# Collapse dashboardSidebar menu after click

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

For the code below, I would like to have a menu (dashboardSidebar) that collapses when any menuItem but item2 is clicked.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(),

  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE, sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
       menuItem("item1", tabName = "item1", icon = icon("newspaper")),
       menuItem("item2", tabName = "item2", icon = icon("tv"),
         menuItem("item2_1",  tabName = "item2_1", icon = icon("tasks")),
         menuItem("item2_2", tabName = "item2_2", icon = icon("flag-checkered")),
         menuItem("item2_3", tabName = "item2_3", icon = icon("user-clock"))))),

  dashboardBody())

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @ismirsehregal, i reposted that question because that other answer doesn't help me, or I don't know how to use it. The answer to the other post explains how to collapse the shidebarMenu after clicking a actionButton (input$hideSidebar), but I need it to collapse after clicking a menuItem. I have tried input$item1 and other combinations but non of them work. Can you help with that? Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is perfect! Thanks a lot @ismirsehregal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE, sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("item1", tabName = "item1", icon = icon("newspaper")),
    menuItem(
      "item2",
      tabName = "item2",
      icon = icon("tv"),
      menuItem("item2_1",  tabName = "item2_1", icon = icon("tasks")),
      menuItem(
        "item2_2",
        tabName = "item2_2",
        icon = icon("flag-checkered")
      ),
      menuItem("item2_3", tabName = "item2_3", icon = icon("user-clock"))
    )
  )),
  dashboardBody(useShinyjs(),
                tabItems(
                  tabItem(tabName = "item1",
                          h2("item1 tab content")),
                  tabItem(tabName = "item2_1",
                          h2("item2_1 tab content")),
                  tabItem(tabName = "item2_2",
                          h2("item2_2 tab content")),
                  tabItem(tabName = "item2_3",
                          h2("item2_3 tab content"))
                ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    shinyjs::toggleClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The only drawback is, that selecting the same `menuItem` twice doesn't collapse the sidebar, due to `input$tabs` remaining unchanged.